# How does [array containsObject:id] method works?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How does `[array containsObject:id]` method works? whether is it compare with addresses or is it compare the given objects properties with the array elements properties ?

Comment: This would be completely answered by thirty seconds of looking at the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you first try looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCEJDI) for this method?

> This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by sending an `isEqual:` message to each of the array’s objects (and passing anObject as the parameter to each `isEqual:` message).

And from the [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCECDG) method:

> If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This last point is particularly important if you define `isEqual:` in a subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a collection. Make sure you also define `hash` in your subclass.

What we can take from this is, unless you're comparing two objects of predefined types (e.g. `NSArray`, `NSString`) where there is already a system-described way of hashing the object's contents and comparing the hashes, you need to provide a `- (NSUInteger)hash` method which returns an unsigned integer whose value, for objects *you* consider equal, will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

it uses `isEqual:`.

if pointer comparison is what you want, use `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`, which will return `NSNotFound` if there is no match.